# Using EF LazyLoading for initializing properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

**UPDATED**: I understood I should not use a `DbSet` so I changed the implementation to an ICollection as suggested by Erenga

Please consider the following classes:

```
[Table("Tenant")]
public class Tenant : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

[Table("User")]
public class User : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The first test creates a new Tenant and a new User and stores them in the appropriate tables.

```
    [Test]
    public void CreateNewUserForNewTenant()
    {
        var user = _applicationContext.Users.Create();
        user.Name = "barney";
        user.EmailAddress = "barney@flinstone.com";

        var tenant = _applicationContext.Tenants.Create();
        tenant.Name = "localhost";
        tenant.Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        tenant.Users.Add(user); // NullReferenceException, I expected the EF would LazyLoad the reference to Users?!
        _tenantRepository.Add(tenant);
        _applicationContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This test will fail on a `NullReferenceException` since the property Users is not initialized.

How should I change my code that I can rely on LazyLoading provided with EF?

Comment: So you expect the logic to initialise `Users` on first access? How were these classes generated?

Comment: There is no lazy loading here.. EF hasnt touched the Users property at this point. Your test only instantiates objects..

Comment: Ok I probably fit in the category idiots now, but could you do me a huge favor and add an example of how I should initialize the DbSet property?

Comment: @Daniel, I am afraid to answer your question, but yeah I kinda did. They aren't generated

Comment: You have an answer here that shows you. Either do that or initialize it in a constructor. Any reference type properties are initialised to null unless you do it explicitly.

Comment: @Haxx See my answer, which is not a recommendation as such. As @SimonWhitehead says, you could either do it as paul suggested, or you could simply initialise `Users` in a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems I see here.

1. As @SimonWhitehead mentioned, reference types are initialized as null by default. Lazy loading works only on entities created by EF. These are actually sub classes of your class that contain addtional logic to lazy load.
2. `DbSet` is not a collection type that is supported on entities. You need to change the type to `ICollection`, `ISet`, or `IList`.

Here's a working example

```
[Table("Tenant")]
public class Tenant : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

[Table("User")]
public class User : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void CreateNewUserForNewTenant()
{
    var user = _applicationContext.Users.Create();
    user.Name = "barney"; 
    user.EmailAddress = "barney@flinstone.com";

    var tenant = _applicationContext.Tenents.Create();
    tenant.Name = "localhost";
    tenant.Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    tenant.Users = new List<User> { user };
    _tenantRepository.Add(tenant);
    _applicationContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, but it just gives the same exception :(. NullReferenceException on adding the user. I could follow the example provided by Paul, and just initialize the collection myself. But for some reason I have an urge to understand why this isn't working...

Comment: @Haxx if you have used `_applicationContext.Tenents.Create()1 to create the `Tenent it should not throw an exception.

Comment: I just updated the question with an exact copy/paste of the test method implementation. maybe I overlook the obvious, but I think I followed your suggestions as you proposed them. (ps: thx :))

Comment: @Haxx apparently you have to initialize the collection property for *new entities*.

Comment: awww kk so there is no "magic way". alright, thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: AHA! i dug a little deeper and now I finally get what the lazy loading thingy is :). when I use your approach I can lazy load the entity if it already exists in the db. e.g. tentants.create(), set the id, and voila, it's bound to the actual row in the db. thx dude :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    var tenant = new Tenant
        {
            Name = "localhost",
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Users = new List<User> { user }
        };
```

Comment: Yeah I can figure out all kind of ways to get rid of my NullReferenceException, but why isn't the lazy loading concept solving this for me? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were expecting something like this (not threadsafe):

```
[Table("Tenant")]
public class Tenant : IEntity
{
    private DbSet<User> _users;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Guid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_users == null)
                _users = new List<Users>();

            return _users;
        }
        set { _users = value; }
    }
}
```

I'm sure the `Lazy<T>` class could be utilised somehow too but I am not familiar with that class.